# Padding-top showing strange behavior

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```css
p.error {
  color: red;
  padding: 5%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  font-size: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px 3px #545454;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

div.alert {
  padding-top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <p class="error">Error: Permission denied!</p>
</div>
```

Which my browser (Google Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133) compiles to this:
[image: ![Screenshot]
I finally got it to vertically center the *div* by using:

```
div.alert{
    padding-top: 22.5%;
}
```

By further testing, I noticed that the browser uses the width instead of the height for *padding-top*.

**My question**: Why does the browser compile the HTML-code like this and how can I get it to vertically center the `div` by using **50%**?

Comment: Just being pedantic here: it's not referred to as "compiling" the HTML code - it's rendering.

Comment: Also, why is the div's height set to 100%? EDIT: don't worry, misread

Answer (score 2):

Padding-top percent is referring to the width of the element. It is part of the W3 CSS Box model specifications:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties

You will not be able to reference height with padding percentages. It will always refer to width.

Comment: Do you mean that the percentages will always be relative to the width, not the height of the element?

Comment: Yes, that is right :P

Answer (score 1):

For centering, I'd recommend you refer to this CSS-Tricks article:
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

I have used this, however I have skipped out the parent element part because the parent is the body:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
.alert {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* for Safari */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

p.error{
    color: red;
    padding: 5%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    font-size: 300%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px 3px #545454;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
    <p class="error">Error: Permission denied!</p>
</div>
```

NOTE: I have only vertically centered the element, not horizontally too.

Answer (score 0):

To vertically center, you want to use an absolute position with `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to put it in the dead center.

```css
p.error {
  color: red;
  padding: 5%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  font-size: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px 3px #545454;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

div.alert {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <p class="error">Error: Permission denied!</p>
</div>
```

You can also use `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` on the parent to center a child in the dead center.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
p.error {
  color: red;
  padding: 5%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  font-size: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px 3px #545454;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

div.alert {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <p class="error">Error: Permission denied!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Again, just being pedantic: this will also horizontally centre the element - which the OP has not asked for. In this case, I presume it's what he wants though.

Comment: Thank you, but why doesn't the browser vertically center it when I use *padding-top:50%*? To me it seems like that should work perfectly fine too..

Comment: @SamMearns Yes, you are right, this is what I wanted.

Comment: @JoshuaWeber That just pushes the element down by 50% of the document height. It's not moving it by the center of the element but by the top of the element. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @JoshuaWeber right, like you said in your post, vertical padding is based off of the element's width. So the value for `padding-top: 50%` will be half of the element's width. It's how the box model works.

Comment: @SamMearns right, I assumed they wanted horizontal centering, too, per their example.

Comment: @JoshuaWeber do you want me to remove the code that horizontally centers this content or is it doing what you want it to?

Comment: @MichaelCoker That's good to know for future usage.. and yes, it is doing exactly what I wanted it to do, thank you